# python grpc deadline exceeded errors in large percentages

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, grpc-java, grpc-python

I'm getting a lot of deadline exceeded errors in `python` `grpc` client calling a `scala` `grpc` server.

I'm reporting metrics from both client as well as server and I have a large discrepency between server reported time vs client reported time which I don't think can be explained by network latency only (as the variance is big). The returned objects are of similar size, I would assume serialization time is negligable compared to network times.

I've set the timeout to 20ms

My client code is simple:

```
self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(...)
self.stub = MyService_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(self.channel)
timeout = 0.02
try:
  start_ms = time.time()
  grpc_res = self.stub.getFoo(Request(...), timeout=timeout)
  end_ms = time.time()
  total_duration_ms = int((end_ms - start_ms) * 1000)
....
except Exception as e:
  status_code = str(e.code()).split('.')[1]
  logger.error('exception ....: %s', status_code) # around 20% deadline exceptions
```

My server code is reporting 5ms on average, the client code is reporting `7ms` on average , but as mentioned , hitting 20% timeouts at `20ms`

Is there a way to debug the root cause for this problem, i.e. lower level logging etc.?

Comment: The average might be 5-7ms, but what about tail latency? It doesn't look like the client code here is measuring latency in the case that the deadline is exceeded. What sort of network connection do you have between the client and the server? Can you characterize it using a tool such as iperf?

Comment: the grpc service is ECS using SRV dns (also tried with load balancer). The client is being run in EC2 instance with very low load. ECS and EC2 are in the same AZ. The latency in the case the deadline is exceeded isn't relevant as I'm trying to only mitigate the deadlines. i've tried upping the deadline to 30ms and it resolved the deadline issue, but obviously the overall mean latency of the client went up

Comment: In our case, we're using grpcio with gevent patch, and seeing a similar deadline exceeded errors, although most of server-side response was made within timeout. Were you able to spot the cause?

Answer (score 4):

You could try running under environment variables:
`GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG GRPC_TRACE=all`
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md